# Dropdown inside the second last column of a table not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

Below in the modal box there is a dropdown in the second last column of an html table.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Launch demo modal
 </button>
 <div class="modal fade margt20 frm-1" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>    
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="dataTable">
         <tr>
          <th>S.No.</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Allocate To</th>
          <th></th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td class="text-center">Bag 1</td>
          <td>210.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">5</td>
          <td class="text-center">1050.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">
           <select id="ddlmanu" name="ddlmanu[]" class="text-success form-control input-sm">
            <option selected disabled value="">-- Select Color --</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Maroon">Maroon</option>
           </select>
           <input type="text" readonly id="txtmanuid" name="txtmanuid[]" class="form-control input-sm" >
          </td>
          <td class="pull-left">
           <button type="button" id="btnsave" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-sm">Save</button>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td class="text-center">Bag 2</td>
          <td>3600.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">10</td>
          <td class="text-center">36000.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">
           <select id="ddlmanu" name="ddlmanu[]" class="text-success form-control input-sm">
            <option selected disabled value="">-- Select Color --</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Maroon">Maroon</option>
           </select>
           <input type="text" readonly id="txtmanuid" name="txtmanuid[]" class="form-control input-sm" >
          </td>
          <td class="pull-left">
           <button type="button" id="btnsave" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-sm">Save</button>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td class="text-center">Bag 3</td>
          <td>3000.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">2</td>
          <td class="text-center">6000.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">
           <select id="ddlmanu" name="ddlmanu[]" class="text-success form-control input-sm">
            <option selected disabled value="">-- Select Color --</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Maroon">Maroon</option>
           </select>
           <input type="text" readonly id="txtmanuid" name="txtmanuid[]" class="form-control input-sm" >
          </td>
          <td class="pull-left">
           <button type="button" id="btnsave" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-sm">Save</button>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script> 
  $(document).on("change","#myModal #ddlmanu",function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   $(this).next().val(value);   
  });
 </script>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when the user selects a text from the `dropdown`, it's value should be shown in the `textbox` below. Here what is happening is in the first row, `dropdown` works perfectly, on selection it's value is shown in the textbox. But when the second or third row dropdown is selected no value is showing in the `textbox`. Why? Where I am wrong.

Please help ??

Comment: the id should be unique in all of the cases.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I understand that but how to achieve that ??

Comment: Please check the updated code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class on each select box `selectBox`

Here is the jQuery code

```
$(document).on("change",".selectBox",function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).next().val(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ritul for answering but nothing is happening

Comment: it will work i tried in my machine bro.. u did some mistake i guess just console 'value',and let me know

Comment: can u send me the code u tried, so that i can check where i am wrong

Comment: @Ratan i made small change in my answer please check now its working fine

Comment: No it's still not working. Ritul this whole thing is inside a modal box not in a web page

Comment: umm then we have to add extra model class before .selectBox class take parent class and add t.. it will work

Comment: I have changed the code in the above with the one u just gave it to me. Please check the code snippet now

Comment: $(document).on("change","#myModal  .selectBox",function(){});  use this one

Comment: you have to add class as well see my full solution there.. in sniff i didnt see any class like selectBox @Ratan

Comment: One more thing, if I want to save this row on button click. How this can b achieved. Can i pick the value of the textbox using data-id

Comment: if you like this solution then dont forgot +1

Comment: yes you can add unique class for input which is related with select box so you can easily get it.

Answer (score 0):

Find , this is working.

```js
$('select').change(function(){
   $(this).next().val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Launch demo modal
 </button>
 <div class="modal fade margt20 frm-1" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>    
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="dataTable">
         <tr>
          <th>S.No.</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Allocate To</th>
          <th></th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td class="text-center">Bag 1</td>
          <td>210.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">5</td>
          <td class="text-center">1050.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">
           <select id="ddlmanu1" name="ddlmanu[]" class="text-success form-control input-sm">
            <option selected disabled value="">-- Select Color --</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Maroon">Maroon</option>
           </select>
           <input type="text" readonly id="txtmanuid" class="form-control input-sm" >
          </td>
          <td class="pull-left">
           <button type="button" id="btnalloctomanu" name="btnalloctomanu" class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-sm">Save</button>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td class="text-center">Bag 2</td>
          <td>3600.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">10</td>
          <td class="text-center">36000.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">
           <select id="ddlmanu2" name="ddlmanu[]" class="text-success form-control input-sm">
            <option selected disabled value="">-- Select Color --</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Maroon">Maroon</option>
           </select>
           <input type="text" readonly id="txtmanuid" class="form-control input-sm" >
          </td>
          <td class="pull-left">
           <button type="button" id="btnalloctomanu" name="btnalloctomanu" class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-sm">Save</button>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td class="text-center">Bag 3</td>
          <td>3000.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">2</td>
          <td class="text-center">6000.00</td>
          <td class="text-center">
           <select id="ddlmanu3" name="ddlmanu[]" class="text-success form-control input-sm">
            <option selected disabled value="">-- Select Color --</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Maroon">Maroon</option>
           </select>
           <input type="text" readonly id="txtmanuid" class="form-control input-sm" >
          </td>
          <td class="pull-left">
           <button type="button" id="btnalloctomanu" name="btnalloctomanu" class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-sm">Save</button>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```